# Google Glass: How to animate change card in cardScrollView?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

Is it possible to do change programmatically the current card to a new position with a slide animation ?

The following code only teleport to the chosen position :

```
cardScrollView.setSelection(cardScrollView.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect timing! This was just added to the GDK in XE21. Check out the new [`CardScrollView.animate`](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView#animate%28int,%20com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.Animation%29) method, which allows you to slide to an existing card as well as insert and delete cards with animations.

Comment: I wanted to ask you how you found the detail information about the XE21, because usually I search here but there is nothing technical: https://support.google.com/glass/answer/6088192?hl=en&ref_topic=6082760. (you seems to be a Google Glas developer so I get it, but I am wondering if there is a better source of information)

Comment: The best place to find a summary of the latest API changes is in our [release notes](https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to simulate a slide animation like the one when you slide manually, but this solution was good enough for me :

```
cardScrollView.setSelection(cardScrollView.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1);
cardScrollView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(cardScrollView.getContext(), true));
```

Your new slide will have a slide animation from the right or the left depending if the second argument if true or false.